# Issue with exporting functions and importing them in other file

Tags: typescript

I have the following structure of files:

```
---utilities
-----index.ts
-----tools.ts
allfunctions.ts
```

In file `tools.ts` I've defined some of the function that I export, using `export const`. For example:

```
export const helloWorld = () => console.log('Hello World');
```

Now, in file `utilities/index.ts` I have imported the file, and exported it as follows:

```
import * as toolsFunction from './tools';

export { toolsFunction }
```

Now, in my `allfunctions.ts`, I am using `helloWorld` function as follows:

```
import { taskFunctions as Utility } from './utilities/';

taskFunctions.helloWorld();
```

This works fine before I compile the code. During compilation, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'helloWorld' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When you import something in typescript with **import**, this is the syntax

```
import * as myModule from './superModule'
myModule.doStuff()
```

or

```
import {doStuff} from './superModule'
doStuff()
```

or

```
import {doStuff as superFunction} from './superModule'
superFunction()
```

So here, it breaks because **taskFunctions** does not exist, and that you should call your helloWorld function with **Utility**.
Try :

```
import { toolsFunctions as Utility } from './utilities/';

Utility.helloWorld();
```

for more information you can also check https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are not calling the `helloWorld()` function with proper syntax. You have exported it as `toolsFunction` but you are importing it as  `taskFunctions` in your `allfunctions.ts`. Further more you need to to call the function based on the new alias `Utility`. So your code should be like below

**tools.ts**

```
export const helloWorld = () => console.log('Hello World');
```

**index.ts**

```
import * as toolsFunction from './tools';

export { toolsFunction }
```

**allfunctions.ts**

```
import {toolsFunction as Utility} from './utilities/'

export {Utility};
```

**usage in app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Utility} from './allfunctions'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 4';

  constructor(){
    Utility.helloWorld();
  }
}
```

Working demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular4-zzhcu5